# Swift: how to order instructions in init method of a subclass

Tags: swift, initialization

I need to implement this class:

```
class PinImageView: UIImageView {

    var lastLocation:CGPoint
    var panRecognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer

    init(imageIcon: UIImage?, location:CGPoint) {
        self.lastLocation = location
        super.init(image: imageIcon)
        self.center = location
        self.panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target:self,  action:"detectPan:")
        self.gestureRecognizers = [panRecognizer]
    }
}
```

I think there is a kind of "cyclic" problem because the compiler wants me to initialize `panRecognizer` before calling `super.init(image: imageIcon)` but `panRecognizer` has `self` as target and we can use `self` only after calling the `super init` method.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a non-optional instance variable

```
var panRecognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer
```

so you have to set a value for it before completing `init`, and specifically as you see, before calling `super`.

It doesn't quite need to be like that. Instead, it can be a lazy loading instance variable, so it's created the first time you request it.

Now, when you `init` you can setup the instance, call super, and then add the gesture recogniser (which will create the gesture in the process).

```
lazy var panRecognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer = {
    return UIPanGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:"detectPan:")
}()
```